# What book(s) to read in order to learn letter-sound correspondence in English?

Tags: grammar, physical-resources

Someone advised me to go to the wikipedia page on "English Ortography" but in the references there are so many books that I don't know which to choose. In the same page there is also a list of letter-sound correspondences but I'd prefer a book because I want something more complete.

I know basic phonetics and I can communicate in English reasonably well.

Comment: I know basic phonetics and I can communicate in English reasonably well; don't know what else to say XD

Comment: I edited the question to include that. hopefully someone can comment on good sources.

Comment: Are you asking this in order to learn pronunciation (i.e. correctly pronounce words you see in writing) or spelling (i.e. correctly writing down words that you hear)? This makes a big difference, because there is more to this question then simply letter-sound correspondences.